# jquery this not working with settimeout, bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, settimeout

so I am trying to do some dynamic hover manipulations, which require using `this` in jquery. For some reason that I cannot figure out, the javascript `setTimeout` function does not seem to support it.

I understand that the `setTimeout` function is not Jquery, but if placed inside a Jquery function, shouldn't it be able to respond to the relevant `this`?

Here is some sample code:

```
var go = false;
var t;
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        go = true;
        alert($('span',this).text());
    },1000);
});
$('.box').mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    if(go){
        alert($('span',this).text());
    }
});
```

when hovering for 1 second it will alert a blank, yet on mouseleave it will alert the correct text even though both alerts are inside a Jquery function with the same selector.

**Why does this happen and how can I fix it?**

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krwb9/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since the callback to `setTimeout()` is executed separate from the main thread, the execution context of the callback will be different so `this` inside the callback does not point the same object as it was outside the `setTimeout`, in this case the `hovered` `.box` element.

One possible solution here is to use the [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method to pass a custom execution context for the callback method

```
 $('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    t = setTimeout($.proxy(function(){
        go = true;
        alert($('span',this).text());
    }, this),1000);
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fWUDR/)

Another solution is to use a closure variable

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    var self = this;
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        go = true;
        alert($('span', self ).text());
    },1000);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pZ7aN/)

Comment: thank you! I used the first one...I use jquery functions inside the setTimeout with their own `this` selectors and the other one made that buggy even if I kept their individual `this`s for some reason

Answer (score 4):

You can just save the value of this somewhere:

```
$('.box').mouseenter(function(){
    var elem = this;
    t = setTimeout(function(){
        go = true;
        alert($('span', elem).text());
    },1000);
});
```

The reason you have to do this is that 'this' gets a new value pretty much whenever a new function gets called. So when the timer stuff calls your inner function, 'this' isn't the same as it is when the mouse stuff calls your outer function.

Technically, the 'this' is called the execution context.

What the code above does is creates a variable inside the closure created when the outer function gets called. We store 'this' in that variable, 'elem', and use it later when the timeout occurs.